# messages are not consumed after reading from queue

Tags: jms, message

Using JMS, to read message from queue code written like:

```
QueueReceiver qReceiver = qSession.createReceiver(queue, getIdCorrelation(msgID));
qReceiver.receive(timeOut);
```

messages are not getting consumed after reading from queue.